# Menu dropdown, the icon doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu where clicking a button shows the menu.

I have to add an icon: > When click the menu is clicked the icon needs to change position, the problem is it does not come back...

Could someone help me to fix this code so that closing the menu would make the icon come back?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  padding: 16px 0px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:before {
  content: "\003e";
  color: #000;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.dropbtn:hover:before {
  content: "\003e";
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: translate(-5px, 5px) rotateZ(90deg);
}
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px
}
#menu-category {
  margin: 0
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 12px 0px 0px 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="work-dd">Work</a>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Overview</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      ....code of menu...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As the error message suggests, you have an error in here: `if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {...`, stating that the method `matches` is unknown for the object `event.target`

Comment: @FDavidov thanks but this it's not the problem, anyway i don't see in console any error in that line.

Comment: Run the snippet and you will see it.

Comment: @FDavidov I try but the menu work, the problem are the icon can not found the good code for let it work well.